# Load data from txt and load the header from the file with python

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a text file (extract_all.txt) that looks like this:

```
'Reswp' : 2.99824206 : 'Disp.' : 0.26170 : 'B'     : 0.10000 
'Reswp' : 2.38923463 : 'Disp.' : 0.19869 : 'B'     : 0.10000 
'Reswp' : 2.371472   : 'Disp.' : 0.20387 : 'B'     : 0.10000
```

I want to load the data where I get the text as a header for the column of data next to it. How can I do this?

So far I have loaded the data as individual columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('extract_all.txt', sep=":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to load the data, but I'd suggest to correct the generation of original file and use some standard format (CSV, Json, ...):

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval


all_lines = []
with open("extract_all.txt", "r") as f1:
    for line in map(str.strip, f1):
        # skip blank lines:
        if not line:
            continue
        line = literal_eval('[' + line.replace(':', ',') + ']')
        all_lines.append( dict(zip(line[::2], line[1::2])) )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_lines)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Reswp    Disp.    B
0  2.998242  0.26170  0.1
1  2.389235  0.19869  0.1
2  2.371472  0.20387  0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the file looks like (no headers, no empty rows)

```
'Reswp' : 2.99824206 : 'Disp.' : 0.26170 : 'B' : 0.10000
'Reswp' : 2.38923463 : 'Disp.' : 0.19869 : 'B' : 0.10000
'Reswp' : 2.371472 : 'Disp.' : 0.20387 : 'B' : 0.10000
```

this should work

```
data = pd.read_csv('extract_all.txt', sep=":", header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame({data.iloc[0, i].strip().strip("'"): data[i+1] for i in (0, 2, 4)})
```

Output (`print(data)`):

```
      Reswp    Disp.    B
0  2.998242  0.26170  0.1
1  2.389235  0.19869  0.1
2  2.371472  0.20387  0.1
```

(Empty rows actually don't matter, it would work anyways.)